# Bumpy ride after brake, strut replacement?

Tags: struts

I just had my front and back brakes, and the right front axle replaced by an auto repair shop. It cost around $600.

However, right after the changes, the car is now moving up and down a lot even on minor bumps, etc. DEFINITELY a very big change since before the repair. I argued with the mechanics, but they said it wasn't their fault.

Anyway, what do I need to do to get it fixed? They suggested replacing the right-front strut (same side for which the axle was replaced), and then alignment at the same time.

The car is a 1999 Elantra, <60k miles on it. I've already spent a lot of money on it, and don't want to continue dumping money into something I'll get rid of within 1-2 years.

Comment: Edited to clarify, and removed unnecessary snark.

Comment: Unnecessary snark? Are you serious? Why do mechanics think that they can get away with being rude and devious while acting like they are doing a favor on the customer? I can't think of any other industry that does that!

Comment: Are you seriously lumping all mechanics in with some who are rude? That's like saying there are no honest lawyers, politicians, or in fact any industry at all. There are some amazing mechanics, some who go the extra mile for no extra reward. Some of whom may be on this site giving free advice and guidance. I know my mechanic has sorted out various things for me that he should have charged for. Simple reason for the edit - it added nothing to the question at all, and in fact could lead to you getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like shocks or struts are blown. Maybe while replacing the front axle they damaged the strut or unseated the spring somehow?

It is strange that is started right after the service. Can you feel that it is coming from the front-right? Or is it affecting the whole vehicle equally? Getting new struts or shocks would most likely solve the problem. Can't really tell you whether they are at fault or not though.

Comment: thanks for your input; i can't really tell if it's coming from the right...the car is just much more bumpy...can this happen due to tire rotation? Not sure if they did that on my car

Comment: Bumpy as in when you hit a bump the car oscillates more? Bumpy as in the car is constantly vibrating up and down? Or bumpy as in when you hit a bump the car pulls left and right more?

Comment: Bumpy as in the car is constantly vibrating up and down...I think...on a very flat patch of road it's almost fine, but mostly it is bumpy....and it doesn't really vibrate per se, just moves up and down....as you can tell, my terminology is horrible.

Comment: @asker sounds like you are describing a blown strut/shock

Comment: so is it the mechanic's fault for doing a bad job on the installation? Because it really did not have this problem at all before they touched it...

Comment: It is possible but I can't say for sure. It does seem odd.